# Why can't I control environment variables via /etc/environment?

Tags: environment-variables

Google search reveals that "/etc/environment" can be used in OS X to set global environment variables (like JAVA_HOME etc, in key-value pairs). I have tried to add following string to this file on OS X Lion:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "FOO=bar" >> /etc/environment'
```

But after rebooting OS X, `echo $FOO` displays empty string.

Am I doing something wrong or is the information on the internet misleading and "/etc/environment" can't be used in OS X, and am I limited to "/etc/launchd.conf"?

Comment: Where does it say /etc/environment can be used?

Comment: @Mark UNIX has different notion for global environment variables? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I meant all the /etc/environment comments are by Linux people my IOSX does not have /etc/environment and you should not alter Apple supplied files in /etc

Comment: @EyeofHell, would you mind rephrasing the question to "How can I set environment variables globally'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/environment` may work in Linux but doesn't in OS X. There exist other options to accomplish similar results though.

### Additional paths

Additional paths can be added in `/etc/paths.d` by creating a text file there listing one path component per line (e.g. `sudo echo /usr/local/superbin > /etc/paths.d/superbin`).

### Other environment variables

As more or less everything is controlled by `launchd` these days global environment variables can be specified directly in `/etc/launchd.conf` as described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/1088558).

Comment: For people on Yosemite: Please note that `/etc/launchd.conf` is no longer processed.  There is therefore no remaining way to set environment variables automatically at startup for Dock/Spotlight-launched applications (really).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for feeding `launchd`, and a discussion of the approaches in the StackOverflow answer mentioned, is provided at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications) by yours truly.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: @DanielLawson I am not sure if the part of the answer above that links to stackoverflow by patrix is more self sufficient then my bit. What do you suggest that I should add?

Comment: It isn't, but the rest of his answer contains stand-alone answers. What should you include? Some of the great content you posted on SO.

Comment: Answer from Patrix on the same point contains:
server + conf. file. It is a good approach of a self sufficient answer without crossing the frontier of plagiarism :).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `/etc/environment` on OSX Yosemite, *but* you need to set up the daemons slurping the file into the environment at start up yourself.

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477515) for helpful and rather extensive details.

Warning: In order to go with the answer above, your `/etc/environment` needs to look different to yours. Be aware of this.